# mysql jdbc incorrect string value

Tags: mysql, unicode, jdbc

I am executing this query

```
insert into tbl (name) values('Î');
```

When I execute this query from my application with jdbc then I get following error

```
Incorrect string value: '\xEF'
```

If I execute same query with Sql Manager for MySql then it executes successfully

my jdbc connection string is like this

```
jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb?useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=UTF-8
```

any idea where am I wrong ?

Comment: Can you please post the code that performs the query? Also, can you verify if the same statement returns the correct value from the mysql console?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your mysql instance might not be configured to accept your character set.  Im not an expert but i saw this in the mysql documentation

```
ALTER TABLE myTable MODIFY myColumn VARCHAR(255) CHARACTER SET utf8;
```

found [here](http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/4.1/unicode.html)